# "npm run dev" takes forever to open browser in default Webpack Simple setup

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I'm using default Webpack Simple setup, not sure why it's now taking about 5 minutes to clear and open a browser window (and then the page content takes another 2 minutes to show up). I don't know how to troubleshoot this issue either.

Any idea?

[Source code here](https://github.com/fabricepallaud/timelog/tree/dev/src)

Just in case below is my webpack.config.js (which I didn't change):

```js
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

Comment: Reading your code, I don't see nothing weird, my first guest would be that Firebase isn't connecting and you get the 'max-connection timeout' or something similar. Can you try to comment firebase load and only run the "main app" (commented code) and tell me if it still loads so slow?

Comment: Are you inside any type of VM? Docker / VirtualBox ?

Comment: Offering a bounty then not doing any reaction to others trying to help you is very insolent. There could be a rule to punish this behavior...

Comment: @ARS81 I have no idea what happened with this question, I always have tons of tabs opened and I guess I just forgot about it. You spent time creating your helpful answer and I would totally want to give you the +50 bounty, but now I'd need to create a +100 one, a bit tough I guess. I'm really sorry :/

Comment: @drake035 Ok, no problem. Thank you for the explanation, and for accepting my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something around your environment/OS/browser, not your Webpack config or your source files. After cloning your files, downloading packages with `yarn`, for me the `yarn dev` command has finished in less than 30 seconds. I've made a [screencast video](https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cF6bQpYvQn) of my build process. I did it on Windows 10 with an Intel Core i3 3220 CPU and 16GB RAM.

My only modification was adding the [speed-measure-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/speed-measure-webpack-plugin) to your `webpack.config.js`:

```
const SpeedMeasurePlugin = require("speed-measure-webpack-plugin");
const smp = new SpeedMeasurePlugin();

let conf = {
  // your config...
}

module.exports = smp.wrap(conf);
```

and the `--progress` param in your `package.json`.

[image: my Webpack build log]

If nothing helps, I would first try to upgrade Webpack and Babel related packages to their latest version. Webpack 4 and Babel 7 are both said much faster...

Answer (score 0):

I had cloned your project to my computer.It only took less than 5 munitus to run a server and open the browser.So I guess may there was something wrong with your local dev-env. I used `yarn` with `v1.7.0` and Node with `v8.11.3` in my Mac.

Comment: But 5 minutes or a bit less than that is an eternity!